# The program has exited with code 0 but it didn't run my code at all

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int favorite_number;

    std::cout << "Enter your favorite number between 1 and 100:";

    std:cin >> favorite_number;

    std::cout << "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code, for some reason once I try to run it it automatically exits and it doesn't ask me an input. Even if I put stdio.h, nothig happens

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: How do you compile and run your program? Did you save the file before compiling?

Comment: I go to the Build Section and Compile the file, afterwards I Build and Execute. Yes, I did save it before.

Comment: Have you tried to use the command shell to run the executable?

Comment: That should not compile at all. Please copy and paste, don't retype. (If that's your actual file, you're editing a different source than you're executing. It happens sometimes.)

Answer (score 0):

I try to compile your code but there is an error on the cin line.
Try to put two colons before the cin clauses.

```
NOT
std:cin >> favorite_number;
BUT
std::cin >> favorite_number;
```

Bye and having a good day

Comment: the actual issue and thats what the question seems to be about is that OP gets a message claiming that their code was executed without errors.

Comment: It still doesn't run but thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing a ":" before "cin" in the following line:

```
std:cin >> favorite_number;
```

It should be:

```
std::cin >> favorite_number;
```

Comment: the actual issue and thats what the question seems to be about is that OP gets a message claiming that their code was executed without errors.

Comment: It still doesn't run but thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 0):

```
"std:cin >> favorite_number;"
```

In the above line of code a ':' is missing before 'cin'.

Rewrite it as below

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  int favorite_number;

  std::cout << "Enter your favorite number between 1 and 100:";

  std::cin >> favorite_number;

  std::cout << "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```